# A condition for irreducibility

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let  $X$ be  a  closed   projective  set. Prove that $X$   is   an  irreducible  set if   and  only  if $X \cap U_i$ is irreducible  for every i=0,...,n; where $\cup U_i$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{P^n}$. For "$\Rightarrow $" I succeded.

Comment: "Closed projective set" just means a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$. I'm writing you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a topological exercise!

> Let $X$ be a topological space, let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open covering of $X$; a subset $Y$ of $X$ is irreducible only if $\forall i\in I,\,Y\cap U_i=Y_i$ is irreducible. Vice versa, if $Y_i$ is irreducible and $\forall i,j\in I,\,Y\cap U_i\cap U_j=Y_{ij}\neq\emptyset$ then $Y$ is irreducible.

**Proof.** Let $Y\subseteqq X$; if $Y$ is reducible, let $Z$ be an irreducible component of $Y$, then
\begin{equation*}
\exists h\in I\mid Y_h=Z\cap U_h\neq\emptyset
\end{equation*}
because $Y_h$ and $Z\cap U_h$ are irreducible. By hypothesis $\forall k\in I,\,Z\cap U_h\cap U_k=Z_{hk}$ is a non-empty open subset of $Z$ and so $Z_{hk}$ is dense in $Z$. By the same reasoning, $Z_{hk}$ is a non-empty, open and dense subset of $Y_k$; then
\begin{equation*}
\forall k\in I,\,Z_{hk}\subseteqq Y_k\Rightarrow Y_k\subseteqq Z\Rightarrow Z=Y.
\end{equation*}
The other implication is tautological! *Q.E.D.* $\Box$

Comment: Could you wrote the details? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @rafa I had correct the statement! ;)

Comment: why $Z_{hk }$ is an open subset?

Comment: $Z_{hk}$ is an open subset of $Z$ because is an intersection of $Z$ and the open set $U_h\cap U_k$.

Comment: In conclusion I have to find a counterexample for "$\Leftarrow$", because I have not the necessary hypotesis.

Comment: For exact: "$\Leftarrow$" is a sufficient but not necessary condition!, indeed, it is exclude the case that there exists $i\in I$ such that $X\cap U_i=\emptyset$. In the case of $\mathbb{P}^n$, you can prove that $X$ is irreducible in an open subset: is it clear this statement?, how do you can prove this? Hint: you are not interested to $U_i$ such that $X\cap U_i=\emptyset$.

Comment: I don't know to prove that statement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong: if $n=1,X=V(x_0x_1)=\{[1:0],[0:1]\}$, we have $X\cap U_0=\{[1:0]\},X\cap U_1=\{[0:1]\}$, these sets are irreducible but $X$ is reducible. Is it all clear?